# What are the common indicators for employment termination?

Tags: termination, performance

To narrow the scope of the question, I will isolate the job to a corporate environment in which the job revolves around the provision of business improvement recommendations and strategic advice to the various clients of the business. It is above an entry-level position but not an executive level job.

I am curious to know broadly what might be the common indicators that users have personally observed when it comes to inevitably losing a job. It's clear to me that there are a plethora of hints or indicators that could allude to the possibility of a termination. However, I'd like to narrow it further to subtle cues that could imply an imminent employment termination.

Theoretical and anecdotal responses are both welcomed.

Comment: The boss calling you into his office and saying "you're fired" is usually a pretty good one ;)

Comment: [Related question](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/14217/2322)

Comment: Unsure why this was downvoted - I genuinely thought it was a legitimate and serious question. Nonetheless, thank you for all the help.

Comment: Hi @coeus, the question focuses on a lot of speculation, which is difficult to answer with facts, references, and specific expertise. If instead you can [edit] the question to focus on a real, actual problem you're facing, we can look at allowing more answers. Broad, speculative questions don't really fit our Q&A model. Good luck! :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Indicators are:

- When your job assignments get less interesting and less difficult but
  others are still getting the good projects
- When your work is not implemented or is completely redone by someone
  else
- When you stop getting invited to meetings pertinent to your job
- When people stop answering your emails in a timely manner (and they
  used to do so)
- When conversations stop when you enter a room
- When you repeatedly get passed around to different work groups never
  staying anywhere long enough to significantly contribute
- When you start getting hassled for little things that didn't bother
  anyone before. Especially easy to prove things like being late.
- When coworkers avoid you
- When managers talk to everyone else except you
- When other people on the same project as you are publically praised
  and you are not
- When you get a performance warning and are put on a Performance
  Improvement plan
- When you feel uneasy at work for no specific reason that you can identify

Comment: +1 Thank you for this list and actually validating the seriousness of the question that was posed.