# Who would be laid off first?

Tags: employees, layoff

My company is experiencing low performance, and this has been a few months. If it's not getting better next year, I'm afraid there could be a round of layoff.

There are many departments and teams. I am the newest member in my team, and the lowest paid. My other collegues are paid 1.5 to 2 times of my salary.

I am wondering, if the layoff really starts, whom will be the first victims? The management level, or technicians such as me?

Comment: [This question](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/14217/2322) and its answers might be incredibly beneficial for you to read.

Comment: I've also voted to close this because right now, fundamentally this is not answerable. There are too many factors which affect this (see the linked question) to really give an actual answer... it's a bit broad. Are you able to focus the question on more answerable specifics?

Comment: Honestly, you can't predict this in advance. The rules for who gets laid of are specific to the company and the circumstances.  All you can do is do your job to the best of your ability and make sure to take time to be positively noticed by management. And avoid anything that could cause negative notice (like being habitually late or frequently complaining about unimportant things or failing to do admistrativetasks like timesheets on time).

Comment: @ChangeMyName - Assume you will be laid off and plan for the future.  Start looking for a new job.  You should never stop looking for a better position.

Comment: I believe this is answerable in the general. Companies lay off usually according to patterns, under different circumstances, and it's possible to describe those patterns, even if they aren't always followed.

Comment: @DJClayworth - In general I agree, but I feel like describing those patterns is likely to lead to issues where people read them, assure themselves "ah, that means it's not me", and fail to prepare for the impending cuts. In light of that, I feel like the only proper response is "if layoffs are coming, you need to have a safety hatch", as Ramhound stated.

Comment: As the others have said, you really have to plan for the worst. You might be the first to go because you're the newest and potentially the one they are most able to survive without. Or it might be one of your colleagues because they cost twice as much and aren't twice as indispensible. Or it might be some random person cut for purely political reasons. Impossible to predict in the general sense, there is nobody here who has a better insight than you have yourself.

Comment: @AdamV I would like to see people given the opportunity to write an answer that doesn't lay us open to that.