# How to get regular feedback from my manager?

Tags: career-development

Recently I had a change of my direct manager. My earlier manager and I used to sit nearby, so we had a lot of interaction informally as well. 
But the new one sits somewhere else(same location) and we manage to just exchange some smiles,  small talk, and an occasionally heads-up on the work. We have not had any 1:1 meetings in last 3 months.

I would like to get some feedback ahead on how I am doing now, so if I have something to address I can do it now rather than wait to find out at the annual review.

How can I get this feedback from a manager who does not seem to do regular 1:1 meetings?

The culture at my workplace is quite relaxed and all our managers are easily approachable.

Comment: Other than your manager is not doing it already, what is the problem?

Comment: @JeffO The problem is that I might get a rude shock during review time. I might be assuming all is well, my manager is happy as he does not feel the need to schedule a 1:1. But it can get horribly wrong.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere This is where I am confused. Is it not the onus of the boss to regularly have 1:1s from his direct reportees ? Atleast the responses to this question http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/14556/should-i-be-scheduling-11-with-the-manager indicate so. In short, is a 1:1 a chance for me to get some feedback ?

Answer (score 3):

> How can I get this feedback from a manager who does not seem to do regular 1:1 meetings?

It sounds like your first step is to talk with your new manager.

Managers will often assume things are working unless you speak up. So, put a meeting on their calendar with the following:

- Discuss preferred management style
- Discuss preferred communication style
- Discuss their expectations of you
- Discuss your performance to date

Most people are generally willing to have a discussion about "how do you like to manage?" - this naturally lets you say, "I like to be managed like X, having 1/1s every 2 weeks is a great way for me to touch base" or whatever is true for you.

Unless your manager has specifically said, "I don't do 1/1s" it's incredibly unlikely you will not get nearly exactly what you are interested in.

I try to do this with every new position I take and have found managers appreciate it, as well. My current boss did not initiate 1/1s with me but after the above conversation we now have 1/1s every 2 weeks (because I want this).

Comment: I find the point `Discuss preferred management style` very intriguing. Infact, it sounds too idealistic(I might be wrong!). What am I supposed to tell him for this?

Comment: @R11G well... if you know your manager hates 1/1s, but loves impromptu meetings or if you just stop by to chat, this helps you know what to pursue. Maybe your manager loves email and would prefer feedback over email. Etc.

Comment: @R11G The thing to note is that discussion should not be just you telling your manager what you prefer but asking your manager how they prefer to manage. Understanding that should help you gauge when you NEED to have a conversation.