# How to market\showcase the work you are doing

Tags: professionalism, software-industry, ethics, appraisal

I work in a software development firm & feel my work is not appreciated as much as it should. Over the period I have seen people (does not work) who highlight their work are the ones who are more successful as compared to those who believes their work will speak for itself.

I have seen those individuals who go out with managers and praise manager all the time gets higher visibility. Many people never criticize the manager even when the manager is wrong. As for me I cannot be part of such meeting and cannot praise anyone when they are wrong.

I don't like to send mails for every small task I do. I am paid to do my work. But some people send mails for every small task they perform. I personally think its unethical.

I wonder how can I market my work or get appreciation for my work ?

How can I publish my work to larger audience without making it look that I am trying to take extra credit.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about marketing/publishing work and not about navigating the workplaces as defined in the [help].

Comment: @CMW: I wanted to know how to showcase your work at your workplace

Comment: Do you mean to your colleagues?

Comment: @CMW:Yeah (my colleagues)

Comment: Pat I'd like to solve the puzzle... GitHub FTW!!

Comment: @JoeStrazzere: Usually you will see such people going out with manager & just try to be in the good books of the manager. In turn whenever the manager get chance, he praises such workers.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere: I can't do that. I cannot be part of such meeting and I cannot praise my manager all the time. I like to point out his mistakes and I expect the same from him. I am looking for other ways to showcase the quality of work I am doing and ways to get credit for it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to gain visibility in the workplace?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/17803/how-to-gain-visibility-in-the-workplace)

Comment: @Brown_Dynamite Clarifying these points in your questions via an [edit] would be a good idea.

Comment: If you want your boss to recognize your great talent then the first thing you need to do is recognize that part of your job is to make your boss look good. Generally, that can be done without playing office politics by accomplishing your assignments with high quality and on time. The other VERY IMPORTANT component that you seem to not want to do is to "not make your boss look bad". Correcting your boss (in the wrong environment) IS BAD. Not only does it infer to others that your boss is incompetent but gives the impression their employees don't respect him/her.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going to have a very poor career if you don't get over your prejudice about offfice politics. It is not unethical to let people know what you have accomplished. It is the smart move, in fact.

As far as disagreeing with the boss, this is something that is best done privately and calmly and always remembering that while you are paid to do your job, he or she is paid to make decisions about how you do your job and thus even when you disagree, you must be aware that the final decision is rightfully the boss's. So choose only important things to disagree about and choose your timing carefully and always express the objections before the decision was finalized not after when it is too late.  And learn to read your boss, some bosses tolerate more speaking up than others. And remember that since smart players only disagree in private, the people you think are only "yes men" may not be.

What you want is to be effective at work and that means learning to play the game. Even if you choose not to go into managment yourself (and frankly people who refuse to play office politics are very bad candiates for management), you want to effect how the work is done and you want to see things done well. So in order to have the effect on the organization you want, you need to build alliances, to make sure that people respect your knowledge and accomplishments and to create a reason why they should listen to you.

Please read up on office politics as there is a lot more there than you think and you are disabling your own ability to work by refusing to undersand how the game is played. Remember, you don't have to be a snake to be effective with office politics. But you are in the game whether you want to be or not and you must learn how to be effective or you will lose every time.

Comment: Even if I want to, I cannot disagree with your points. Thank you!!!