# Very frustrated about recognition at work - How to proceed

Tags: management, career-development, communication

Sorry, multiple part question, please let me know if I need to split it out.

**Summary**

I feel I was not properly recognized for something I should have, should I point out that concern to my manager.  I read [this excellent answer](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/11816/why-is-it-important-to-gain-visibility-in-the-workplace/11818#11818) by `enderland`, and based on that I feel that I have the productivity part down, but it seems that Image/Exposure have been lacking so that I can meet my deadlines.

**Details**

Recently a project finished up and a higher manager that was not involved on the project that leads our "All Hands" meeting announced the end of the project.  He mentioned how another developer was "outstanding" on the project.  I agree, he did hard work (working over the holiday to finish up), but that is not the part that I have an issue with.  I felt that I also did "outstanding" on the project, and this other manager did not mention me.  My direct manager that was in the meeting did not say anything about my involvement on the project.  He did make some other comments about the project, so he had opportunity.

I looked at the percent of authorship and I have more than double anyone else on the project and more than all other developers combined (build files, resharper files, and other files of this type are ignored for the check-in).  I also received positive comments from the clients, these are usually read aloud in the "All Hands" meeting.  This was not done either.  At this point I want to send a screenshot of the % Authorship to my direct manager, he may not know about this.  How I feel about that is, if my managers don't know there biggest contributors are then is this the place for me?

We recently had annual reviews so I have just brought up several points (extra projects, building up our library, building up our KB, and much more) about how I was going above and beyond what was needed.  I was told that "You are doing better than everyone else" by my direct manager.  I have not been here long, but based on my experience from my last company, I was commonly told what I wanted to hear just to keep me working.  I.E. I was never promoted, never given raises, never mentioned, but given high praise in closed doors quite often.  This feels like I am in the same boat as before.

**Question(s)**

First, I want to know, is it ok to send information to a manager stating that they made an oversight on an All Company announcement.  It seems no matter how I phrase that I comes out as, YOU WERE WRONG, FIX IT!  That just goes against Image and Exposure.

Second, I want to know if should I consider my future with a company that is obviously not technical.  My frustration comes from managers not understanding the difference between someone that does accurate estimates, produces finished work on time, helps others with their work, researches software for the direct manager, does 2+ demonstrations a month to the team with the direct manager in the room on how to help improve something with development in general, and someone who demonstrates leadership skills vs someone that just works their hardest and tells everyone how hard they worked so it is "perceived" they are a harder worker.  If a manager cannot "perceive" from the extra work that I do, and directly telling him about it is the only way, that directly impacts the bottom line.

Lastly, All the above was mentioned in the annual review except the % Authorship.  My manager had already had numbers picked for my review, and had not taken any of this into consideration (based on his comments of, oh yes, I forgot about that, ect.).  After mentioning these, none of this made any difference on my review, all the numbers stayed the same.  I am really trying my best to remain open to my managers perspective (restrictions on how much change he can make, how much is on his plate, ect), but I should at least be mentioned for my work.  What I would really expect is a promotion, since I asked for one, or at least an explanation of why I cannot have one.

I hope that this is not just a rant and that there is something that I can do to improve my career going forward.  I am fine with improving the situation here, because there are several pros to this company.  However, finding another place is also an option if necessary.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere That may be the best option. My only concern with that, is that is exactly how the format of the annual review was. My feeling is that did not get me anywhere positive how I am seen on the company.  I am not sure that my direct manager is relaying my successes to anyone else.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Thanks for the advice.  I will see if he has time next week when he is back in.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Ha, no.  We have an abundance of managers here. That one is a third manager not part of today's conversation.  And is part of the reason why I am so frustrated.  I move from project to project and none of them talk to each other about what I work on. +1 for great memory.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere P.S. There are two more managers involved in the projects that I work on.  So in 1 year I have had 5 managers.  All still here, it is very complicated to know who to report to, ect.

Comment: I can do the talk first, not rant, and how bad they are with ease.  How can I bring up the points about my frustration without mentioning the meeting, considering that everything else was already brought up in the annual review.

Comment: I think that women just have a harder time being visible. You're going to have to be [twice as vocal about what you do](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/judy-giordan/why-bragging-is-good-for-women_b_3623772.html?ncid=edlinkusaolp00000003&ir=Technology). I'm sure you've experienced the way you can state an idea and everyone looks at you like you're an idiot, then a man can restate your idea and he's a genius. You need to combat the fact that you're just less visible.

Comment: Do you want a raise, recognition or both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to know, is it ok to send information to a manager stating that
>   they made an oversight on an All Company announcement.

Not a great idea.

Talk with your Manager first. Dumping email data on him/her is unlikely to get you where you want to be. And as you point out, it will most likely just come across as a rant.

> Second, I want to know if should I consider my future with a company
>   that is obviously not technical.

Perhaps. That's something only you can answer.

> Lastly, All the above was mentioned in the annual review except the %
>   Authorship...

I don't see a real question here.

You are unhappy with the review and the review process. Ok.

Now are you unhappy enough to leave? Only you can answer that question. The answer to that will guide your actions.

Answer (score 4):

On the first point, I'd consider more carefully what are you really wanting for a fix here? Are you wanting there to be another "All Hands" meeting where your praises can be sung just because you feel left out? I could see setting up a meeting with the manager and asking, "Why didn't I get mentioned in the All Hands meeting?" so that you could see how are you perceived as you describe yourself here as the hardest working person that deserves some kudos. To say that they are wrong for leaving you out is ignoring what view they may have had in seeing things from a different angle. Have you considered that while you may do a lot this is what the company sees as "normal" from you that may not be the same as what is expected of others? A conversation with you asking questions to see their perspective would go over way better than being the baby that wants attention and feels slighted here.

On the second one, this I see differently. Your direct manager told you, "You are doing better than everyone else," and somehow that isn't good? Really? You may want to consider having the conversation about what company recognition programs are there, what you want on a regular basis and how close are you to being promoted. [Econ 101 management](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2006/08/09.html) is somewhat old but still relevant about gaming the system. % Authorship may not be as big a deal in some ways as some people may reduce the amount of code by removing code smells that how is this accounted for properly? How are design decisions rewarded if it is just the amount of code that counts at the end of the day?

On the last point, I'd ask the manager, "What do I have to do in order to be promoted?" so that you can get an answer of what skills are they wanting to see as perhaps it is different than your perspective.

Comment: 1st point: The concerns with talking with the "All Hands" manager is that is going over the head of my direct manager.  I feel that this is the information that should have been relayed by my direct manager, either before that meeting or my direct manager should have said something.  If I am indeed "doing better than everyone else".  To avoid complaining to the company, I am doing research here first to see what is acceptable.  I feel that I was wronged, I want to know what is acceptable. I have not complained before so I doubt they see me like that now.  2nd point, it is good to be told ...

Comment: I am doing better, but if that is a hidden comment behind closed doors.  I am working hard, but if others don't know about it, I do not get the projects I need or the promotions I need.  I fall behind like I did before.

Comment: While you feel wronged, what kind of things would you want as a fix? Would you want the next "All Hands" to start with a, "We're sorry we forget to acknowledge..." message so you are mentioned? Do you even know what you want here?

Comment: I would expect that the next time I do a large amount of work for a project my direct manager would let the "All Hands" leader know I should be mentioned.  At this point that other project is over, and not much can be done.  Even the announcement would look bad at this point.  I need to make sure that the breakdown in communication of what I do that is above and beyond gets to the right people.