# How to create objective promotion policy

Tags: promotion

I work for a software company that has expanded exponentially in past two three years. Considering a team that is going to be 300 employees soon creating technical mentor-ship and leadership positions is going to be imminent.

All that said, what are the objective ways of creating promotion/career path policies? I am aware that some companies do personality+tech tests and training. After which they decide what are the most suitable career paths for employees. Are there industry accepted ways(tests+training) to do this?

**--Edit--**

Let's break this question in couple of mini questions

1. Is it ok to run an analytical report on internal issue tracking systems? For instance reports showing how many tickets the given employee has closed or What is the average time to close a ticket etc
2. Are there any predictive index(assessment) tools that can be used? There is one [here](http://www.hiresuccess.com/personality-test.htm) but I am not sure how useful it is outside of hiring work flow
3. What kind of leadership training exist to grow internal employees to higher roles

Comment: An interesting question, though not one I can answer. If you haven't already you might want to look further into the subject of "talent management" which is the (appallingly marketing-oriented) phrase for this general subject: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talent_management

Comment: Not an answer but might still be insightful: ["How to move from middle management to upper management in the software industry?"](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/48641/how-to-move-from-middle-management-to-upper-management-in-the-software-industry/48642#48642)

Comment: This is a little broad. You might try doing a bit of research and asking a more pointed question, such as debating two different approaches, and asking for improvements to your methodology/ideas.

Comment: What is the goal of the policies? In the companies I've worked in, the employee decided what career path they wanted to pursue, not the company, so I'm a little confused about what you're looking for. Are you looking for guidelines that an employee who wanted to advance to a leadership position could follow to make them a candidate for when such a position opens up?

Comment: [How StackOverflow does (part of) it](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/how-much-should-you-pay-developers/) , and links therefrom. Four years old, but I imagine the principles are the same.

Comment: @ColleenV Rephrasing the question, when too many employees want to be a TL, or a mentor or a manager how do we objectively asses which one is more eligible than the other.

Comment: @Sap If you edit that into your question,  it will pop it back up the list of active questions and it may get reopened.

Comment: @ColleenV Made the edit, let's see what happens