# What to do if my training work is getting unnoticed?

Tags: professionalism, training

As a part of six months training program, the very first assignment included some tutorial followed by a mini project. The tutorials had some loopholes in between.When I was implementing the tutorials I corrected mostly all the faults in the tutorial and submitted the assignment.

But the reviews from my senior  were unexpected. The ratings were quite low from what I have expected. The review included that I should correct the defects in the tutorial and the defects were mentioned which were already corrected by me.

I was really frustrated as it took some serious efforts from my side and most probably they have not noticed my assignment and given a low-obvious-type rating.

What should I do? Should I write back that all these things were already corrected by me and might have gone unnoticed ? or leave as it is as it's my first assignment and I don't want to make them feel that I am a complaining guy?
Also, does it show that people in this company are ignorant or carefree? Should I think again to join this company?

PS: It's 6-month off-site training program.

Comment: Read this as required reading for this situation - http://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/11816/2322

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What should I do?
>
> Should I write back that all these things were already corrected by me
> and might have gone unnoticed?

You have just answered your own question. **Yes**, you write back to your manager that you have indeed made the expected corrections already, and the effort might have gone un-noticed. And it happens often. Instead of getting frustrated, just leave a mail(or talk also) notifying him/her about the change.

> or leave as it is as it's my first assignment and I don't want make
> them feel that I am a complaining guy?
>
> Also, does it show that people in this company are ignorant or carefree?

Again, you have answered your own question. If you ignore, then you are  definitely not respecting your work. And that is a clear sign of ignorance.

**Solution?**

As already said, mail/talk to your manager regarding the mistake from their side. You might also earn some brownie points for identifying that mistake and making efforts for correcting it.

> Should I think again to join this company?

You are over-thinking/exaggerating. Please don't take such decisions without even knowing why a mistake happened, and not putting in efforts for correcting it.

Answer (score 3):

First, you need to assume that the corrections you made could have still been incorrect. So when you talk to your manager again, tell him you had made those corrections and the date of them and then ask him if your corrections were in error. This conversation serves several purposes. First it lets them know you are taking the feedback seriously. Next it tells them that the corrections were made before the feedback, so if they are, in fact, correct, you look good. Next if the fixes were not correct, it opens up a dialog to help you to understand why they were not correct so you can actually fix your performance. If at all possible, I would do this in a face-to-face meeting or phone call. Email would be the last preference for this sort of thing. I also would do it immediately.