# What's the best way to ask for promotion?

Tags: manager, performance-reviews

I work in a pre-ipo startup company. I am a senior level engineer. One of my team member is also a senior level engineer and we work together on a project. I feel my manager wants to promote him instead of me in next 6 months (mostly because he is in the team longer than me). Although my performance in the project is better than him.

In this situation, **what can I bring up this to my manager?**

P.S. Plz don't ask whether better performance is just my feeling not objective. What I want to know is what to do in this situation. Thanks

Comment: From a senior engineer, what is a promotion? Do you have an individual contributor level that is a higher title, such as a principle engineer? Or is a promotion into a leadership or managerial position?

Comment: The best way to ask for a promotion or pay increase is to identify what it is you are asking for: do you want more money? a new title? authority? Then present information to your boss about why you deserve it. Bring the receipts. PS: Telling us not to ask how you know your performance is better doesn't allow us to get all of the information needed to answer this question.

Comment: I'd read this first - https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/11816/why-is-it-important-to-gain-visibility-in-the-workplace - as it's highly relevant to this situation.

Answer (score 0):

> I feel my manager wants to promote him instead of me in next 6 months
>   (mostly because he is in the team longer than me). Although my
>   performance in the project is better than him.
>
> In this situation, what can I bring up this to my manager?

If you feel you deserve a promotion, you should ask for one. Find a quiet time to talk and start with something like "Boss, I think I deserve a promotion." Then go into the reasons why you deserve one.

Talk about how hard you have worked. Mention the difference you have made to the company. Talk about how long it has been since you joined (or since you were last promoted). Talk about the kinds of things you want to do going forward. Explain why this will be very valuable to the company. Make sure you indicate what position you want to get promoted into.

Whatever you do, do not indicate that you want a promotion simply because you believe your coworker will be getting a promotion 6 months down the road. Do not indicate that you believe your performance on your current project has been better than this coworker. Whatever is going on with your coworker is simply not relevant to you or your potential promotion. Talking about someone else is a very weak argument.