# Should I change my decision to stay current organisation after dropping resignation

Tags: work-environment, work-life-balance, career-switch, appraisal

I am in a quandary right now.

I have a work experience of 3 years.

The work experience in the current company, for namesake let this company be "A" is 1 year.

Due to poor appraisal and difficult work environment, I dropped my resignation.
But the learning is great in this current company "A". This company has very less resources, so more responsibility and ownership on its employees and offers great salary. But however, this time, the hike was very less and I got **ZERO** hike after being one year. I felt that I was being targeted for being an introvert (I don't join with the team for lunches and other social gatherings as I am not comfortable with them).

The new offer which I received in another company, say "B", does not offer great career growth and it has a lot of employees. So, less ownership and responsibility on each project for each employee and less salary and hence great work life balance. But career growth for learning is not that great in this company "B"

Should I choose Company "A" for career growth or company "B" for work-life balance and decent income?

I know, the decision depends on me and my environment.

My thinking :

I want to stay at company "A" only. But the work environment is difficult and a little too much pressure. And I collapse under this pressure. But I want to learn more here which I won't be able to get in the company "B"

In the long run, career growth seems to be more important that work-life balance. But then, I also think that, I can take the offer at company "B" and try some freelancing and stuff to supplement more income. But again then, since company "B" has more people, I will be disposable and my presence won't make a difference, right?

Can someone help me with what I should be doing? Is my thought process and thinking, correct?

And if I want to retain in company "A", should I make a condition that, I will stay here only if some hike is provided to me, or should I just be happy that they have retained me (if that happens) and ask no hike at the expense of good learning/career growth?

Please help me with this on what to do and how to do in my situation?

Comment: You weren't _targeted_ for being an introvert because it wasn't done intentionally. Your team doesn't know you. You're still young and fresh, and this is something you have to work on, regardless of whether you stay with company A or not. It's something many of us struggle with, including myself. Have a look at this [great answer](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/11818/9549) by enderland on a similar question.

Comment: When you say you "dropped" your resignation, do you mean you submitted it (as in provided notice) or rescinded it (you had already resigned, but you chose to stay after all?) I'm assuming the former, but the wording makes it sound like the latter.

Comment: I submitted my resignation.

Comment: @rath , thank you. I will work on that. But can you provide an answer or a suggestion to my current dilemma

Comment: I know, its not reasonable for me to expect a tailor made answer/suggestion/opinion to my question. But I have given a thought to this for many days, before even thinking of asking out here to a global network. So, I request, if anyone can provide me a straight forward solution of what's best. I know, it all depends on me. But just would require your suggestion/opinion

Comment: This is very confusing.  If I am understanding correctly, you have already resigned your position at company A.  How is staying at Company A still on the table?  Are they begging you to stay on?

Comment: You *don't have* a dilemma. You've resigned. Company A might put up a fight to keep a star performer, but they have already given you a poor appraisal and doubled down with 0% raise (not even inflation). Why would they let you rescind your resignation? You have no future there - go with B or look for other options.

Comment: **It sounds like you simply want less responsibility**, since you accepted a job for less pay, of course none of this makes logical sense since you are leaving the company because you didn't get a yearly raise.  You are are worried about being disposable at a company where you will have less responsibility, but it already sounds like you are unfortunately already disposable at your now previous company, since they didn't give you a raise due to your performance.  I don't mean to point out these issues, but it simply sounds, you want less responsibility and are willing to accept the pay cut.

Answer (score 2):

So you didn't get a big raise. So what? You are, by your own admission, a junior dev, and have only been there a year. That's barely enough time to get comfortable with most code bases, and learn the basic processes.

What have you contributed to the company to be worthy of a major raise? Probably nothing, and you need to understand that this is the only thing that matters as far as promotions and raises are concerned.

Learn to navigate office politics. Engage with your coworkers. Do lunch at least *some* of the time. Participate in events, and be generally well liked, especially by your managers.

Always choose growth over stability if you can afford to (you didn't just have a kid, etc.), as it will lead to greater rewards in the medium to long-term. If the expected growth between two opportunities is similar, choose money.

That being said, you've now ruined your reputation by submitting your resignation. Your boss and coworkers will consider you a flake from now on, so maybe it would be best to jump ship.